# Is there a way to get urls from multiples li tags from onclick attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

This a nodejs and puppeteer proyect.
I have multiples `li` tags that contain `onclick` attribute. When I click each `li` it's redirect to specific url.
What I'm trying to do is get each URL.

The `li` tags look like the following:

```
<li onclick="document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=121&amp;productId=101&amp;lang=es';">

<li onclick="document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=122&amp;productId=102&amp;lang=es';">

<li onclick="document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=123&amp;productId=103&amp;lang=es';">
```

The `document.location.href` property is `https://resale-intl.tickets.com/` URL.

So after click each `li` tag it's redirect to:
`https://resale-intl.tickets.com/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=121&amp;productId=101&amp;lang=es` which is the full url. I'm trying to get this URL of each `li`.
What I have have so far is the following:

```
         async function getUrls(){

              const getPartidos = await newPage.$$("li")

                  console.log(getPartidos)// The output is each li tag

                      for (const partido of getPartidos) {

                             const urlPartidos = await newPage.evaluate((element) => {

                                  return element.onclick.toString()

                             }, partido)

                             console.log(urlPartidos)

                      }

               }

         getUrls()
```

The output of `console.log(urlPartidos)` is the following string:

```
function onclick(event) {                                                                                               
         document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=121&amp;productId=101&amp;lang=es';
      }
function onclick(event) {                                                                                               
         document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=122&amp;productId=102&amp;lang=es';
      }
function onclick(event) {                                                                                               
         document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=123&amp;productId=103&amp;lang=es';
      }
```

I was trying to access to the `onclick` function using `toString()` method. But after this I don't know how to access and get the full url.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your question correctly and which technologies you are using. But this example with native JavaScript

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
lis.forEach((li) => {
  console.log(li.getAttribute('onclick').split("'")[1]);
})
```

```html
<li onclick="document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=121&amp;productId=101&amp;lang=es';">1</li>

<li onclick="document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=122&amp;productId=102&amp;lang=es';">1</li>

<li onclick="document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=123&amp;productId=103&amp;lang=es';">1</li>
```

`Output`

```
"/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=121&productId=101&lang=es"
"/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=122&productId=102&lang=es"
"/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=123&productId=103&lang=es"
```

Comment: Hi, the tecnology that I'm using are nodejs and puppeteer.

Comment: `console.log(li.getAttribute('onclick').split("'")[1]);` And I get `TypeError: li.getAttribute is not a function` also with `console.log(li.attr('onclick').split("'")[1]);` And same error: `TypeError: li.attr is not a function`

Comment: @OmarGiancarlo you'd need to run this code inside an `await page.evaluate(...)` call.